# What is the dimension of wavefunction in spherical polar coordinates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I understand that the dimension of the wavefunction in Cartesian coordinates is $L^{-3/2}$ since the norm squared of the wavefunction is the probability density, where probability is a dimensionless quantity. I wanted to know if any of this changes in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: How could it? A change of coordinates can't change the dimensions of a quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Since $r^2\sin\vartheta\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\vartheta\,\mathrm d\varphi$ has units $L^3\,\text{rad}^2$, the wavefunction thus has units $L^{-3/2}\,\text{rad}^{-1}$. But since $\text{rad}$ is actually a dimensionless, made-up unit for our own convenience, in the end, the wavefunction's units are the same in either case.